# Replace df1 column values with df2 column values - values of df-1 column-3 are columns of df-2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Values of df-1 column-3 are columns of df-2. I want to replace the df1 column-3 values with corresponding values in df-2 with col1 as the index.

```
df1 looks like:
col1    col2    col3
----------------------
label1  val1    A
label2  val2    NaN
label3  val3    B

df2 looks like:
col1     A      B
-------------------
label1   v1    NaN 
label2   v2    NaN
label3   v3    v2


final df1 should be:
col1    col2    col3
----------------------
label1  val1    v1
label2  val2    Nan
label3  val3    v2
```

I can achieve this by converting the data frames to list of lists, processing it and again converting the list of lists to data frame. But I would like to know is there any way to directly accomplish this task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`df.lookup()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df   = df.set_index('col1')
df_n = df.dropna()

df.loc[df_n.index, 'col3'] = df2.set_index('col1').lookup(df_n.index, df_n.col3)

        col2    col3
col1        
label1  val1    v1
label2  val2    NaN
label3  val3    v2
```

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I have added the reset_index to make it a complete data frame which includes index as a column.  df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)